# How to use ErrorMessage on properties and still save with Entity Framework without it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a user model class that has a `RepeatedPassword`, this property should not be saved in the database, it's just to enter in the validation Model, using ASP.NET MVC.

I put the data annotation `[NotMapped]` on this property, but still when I try to save I got a exception that this property should not be empty.

```
[NotMapped]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Passwords don't Match")]
public string RepeatedPassword { get; set; }
```

I even tried to add this on my context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Ignore(a => a.RepeatedPassword);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Compare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.compareattribute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) attribute to ensure the `RepeatPassword` is the same as `Password`. Since `Password` is required, `RepeatPassword` would be required by definition, so you can remove the `[Required]` attribute from `RepeatPassword`.

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
[StringLength(Constants.MaxPasswordLength, ErrorMessage = "{0} must be  between {2} and {1} characters long", MinimumLength = Constants.MinPasswordLength)]
public string Password { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
[Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match")]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```